# Making first login system. Selecting SQL Column not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to make my first login system. For some reason when I try to get the password from my database it doesn't give a value? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The error is somewhere between $sql and $db_password.

@LFlare Im not sure what the DESC users thing is. Here is a picture of the table, I wasn't sure how you wanted it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmurM.png

Thanks!

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        include_once("db.php");
        $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
        $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);

        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);

        $password = md5($password);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $id = $row['id'];
        $db_password = $row['password'];

        //echo "Password: $password";
        //echo "DB Password: $db_password";

        if ($password == $db_password) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            header("Location: index.php");
        } else {
            echo "You didn't enter the correct details!";
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
            <input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
            <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the value of `$row` you got?

Comment: The value of $row is nothing.

Comment: Try with this query $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' LIMIT 1";

Comment: You should  then `echo` the `$sql` and run it directly in your database to check if there is any issue with your sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        include_once("db.php");
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlcon, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlcon, $_POST['password']);
        // If you want to make sure username is alphanumeric, you can do
        // $username = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlcon, $_POST['username']));

        // Do not use these, mysqli_real_escape_string is enough to prevent injection attacks. Furthermore, you may be compromising user security by remove special characters in passwords.
        // $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
        // $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
        // $username = stripslashes($username);
        // $password = stripslashes($password);

        // $password = md5($password); This is very susceptibile to rainbow table attacks, do something like a loop
        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i ++) {
            $password = md5($password . $username); // Looping the md5 a thousand times and salting it with the username is good practice too.U
        }

        $userQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' LIMIT 1";
        $user = mysqli_query($sqlcon, $userQuery);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($user) > 0) { // If user exists,
            $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user); // mysqli_fetch_arrays put values into $user[0], $user[1], etc.
            $id = $user['id'];
            $databasepass = $user['password'];

            if ($password === $databasepass) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                header("Location: index.php");
            } else {
                echo "Password is incorrect";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Username does not exist";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Username or Password not filled in";
    }
    echo $password;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
            <input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
            <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Your db.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "users";

$sqlcon = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die ("MySQL Database Connection Error");
}
?>
```

Comment: It's telling me the Username doesn't exist with that code.

Comment: @Sphiinx, sorry, I accidentally equaled too much, try the code again. If it still doesn't work, can I have your database structure and a sample row as an example?

Comment: @LFlare  Just a heads up, the password comparison portion is still vulnerable to a weak typing bypass. Throw a triple equals on that badboy.  https://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/2014/12/18/php-weak-typing-woes-with-some-pontification-about-code-and-pen-testing  Figured from your comments regarding security, you'd appreciate it ;)

Comment: @Tim, Thanks for the heads up! I've edited my code again, Sphiinx might want to try the new code

Comment: @LFlare it still seems to tell me the Username doesn't exist. How can I give you my database structure?

Comment: @Sphiinx, can you run `DESC users;` and paste the output on your original post? Also, please paste a sample row from your `users` table, preferably the one row that contains the `username` you are checking.

Comment: Edited it and added the info.

Comment: Can you take a picture of your table values and can you tell us what `username` you are trying to check for?

Comment: @Sphiinx, I've made some revisions, test the code I gave you before doing the previous thing I asked of you ^_^

Comment: I'm trying to login with test as the username and test as the password, which is the same in the table. I believe the picture I linked shows the table values? http://i.imgur.com/WkZV7IZ.png

Comment: @Sphiinx I... believe that you did not insert into the table the values? Try clicking on `Go`

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the values are inserted into the table? http://i.imgur.com/Oi8WN71.png

Comment: @Sphiinx, okay, that's what I needed. Can you check if $db is connected to the correct database? If yes, can you check if you are running the latest code that I wrote? I edited it quite a bit... if it still doesn't work, invite me to a chat so I can work on it live for you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110453/discussion-between-sphiinx-and-lflare).

Answer (score 0):

You have your $db, and $sql backwards in `mysqli_query`.

`$query = mysqli_query($sql, $db);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Also, try avoid using md5, and use PHP's password_hash, http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php.

Currently, if the DB gets exploited, it's vulnerable to rainbow table attacks.

Comment: Seriously now? $sql is the query, $db is the connection. Also, the link you linked, mysql_query is deprecated. In addition, rainbow table attacks can be more or less avoided by running the md5 multiple times with salts.

Comment: @LFlare Ahh!!  You're totally right, I got the link for mysql_query instead of mysqli_query.  The depreciation warnings make sense now.

Comment: Haha, in mysqli_query, the connection is the first argument, the query is the second. @Tim